# node.js with sails.js pm2 socket.io reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I use node v0.12.2, sails.js v0.11 and pm2 0.12.13, in the browser appear 'Connection closed before receiving a handshake response' and 'Error: xhr post error'. How can I fix this?

config.session

```
adapter: 'redis',
host: 'localhost',
port: 6379,
ttl: 0,
db: 'sails'
```

config.socket

```
adapter: 'socket.io-redis',
host: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379,
db: 'sails'
```